# Using a 4 digit bubble display on Msp430

Tags: c, msp430

I am working on a project that entails using the 4digit bubble display to display an ever increasing counter and looping back around, along with other features. My problem is that I can't seem to figure out how to change just one single bubbles display. I can change them all to the same number or individually turn them off. But can't seem to change one without affecting the others. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my wiring layout if it helps:

Cathode 1: 1.4

Cathode 2: 1.7

Cathode 3: 1.5

Cathode 4: 1.6

Segments:

A 2.1

B 2.2

C 2.3

D 2.4

E 2.5

F 2.6

G 2.7

Anode dp GND.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is a common-cathode display. To display a number on it, you will need to multiplex the digits: set up a timer interrupt to fire at about 250 Hz to sequentially display one of the digits.

That is, to display the number "1234", your display should cycle between the following states 250 times per second:

```
1 _ _ _   (cathode 1 active with segments B and C)
_ 2 _ _   (cathode 2 active with segments A/B/D/E/G)
_ _ 3 _   (cathode 3 active with segments A/B/C/D/G)
_ _ _ 4   (cathode 4 active with segments B/C/F/G)
```

So long as you switch between the digits quickly enough, these four digits will look like a single number.